# How to sum column from different database with different number of rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

## Table1

| NO | VALUE1 | ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 |

## Table2

| NO | VALUE2 | ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 20 | 2 |

hi guys, i'm newbie in sql prgramming, i want to sum value1 from table1 with value2 from table2. I hope the total is 1030.

I have try this query :

```
SELECT 
SUM(VALUE1 + VALUE2) AS TOTAL 
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.NO = TABLE1.NO 
GROUP BY TABLE1.NO
```

but the result is 2030 instead of 1030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is producing the right result.
What you are having in the result is the sum of 1000+10 and 1000+20
You are joining table1 and table2 with `TABLE2.NO = TABLE1.NO`

Since, the value of `NO` in table2 is 1 for both the rows, the join produces the sum of 1000+10 and 1000+20. To check how that seems, you can see by trying following query:

```
SELECT 
VALUE1,
VALUE2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table2.NO = table1.NO
```

You'll get the following:

| VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10 |
| 1000 | 20 |

What you might need is the following:

```
SELECT
 SUM(valueToAdd) 
 FROM(
SELECT VALUE1 AS valueToAdd FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT VALUE2 AS valueToAdd FROM TABLE2
) a;
```

The `UNION ALL` will give you all the columns from `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`
and then you can use the `SUM` to add it all up.

Comment: Hi @Asgar thanks for your answer, it's totaly work. Your answer is very valuable for me as a beginner.